# user authentication in web app on aws

Tags: authentication, web-applications, amazon-web-services

I am trying to host a HTML/JS based app on AWS. I need to implement a signup/login feature for this app, now I understand I'll have to have a database (mysql will work?) here. However is there an off-the-shelf way of implementing something like user sign-up for an app on AWS? I don't want to take care of numerous security and authentication scenarios my self.

Comment: 6 years later...  What framework/language?

Answer (score 1):

The AWS SDK for Browser is made for this: https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/

> Social Login
>
> Secure your web app's access to AWS resources without any server-side
>   code. AWS SDK for JavaScript makes it easy for you to integrate with
>   Amazon Cognito, which allows you to provide customizable levels of API
>   access to unauthenticated and authenticated users. Amazon Cognito is
>   easy to set up with Facebook, Google, Login with Amazon, and any
>   OpenID Connect identity provider. To learn how to do this, visit the
>   AWS JavaScript Development Blog.